# Setting TRUE 1080p output on Mac Mini HDMI?

Tags: display, mac-mini, hdmi

At my church we have a display system that uses a HDMI splitter to drive three 1080 TVs as well as an old (might be relevant) 1080 monitor. We were running this setup off a 2012 MacBook pro with a Thunderbolt to HDMI adapter with no issues. On the MacBook pro the external display setup was recognized as a TV, and I was able to select 1080p from the list of resolutions, which worked properly.

We just upgraded to a new MacMini with the built in HDMI port. Unfortunately, when I plug the HDMI cable going to the splitter into the HDMI port (along with a separate monitor connected to one of the USB-C ports), the external displays don't work, showing an out-of-range error indicating a bad resolution. What it looks like is that the new computer is recognizing the splitter as a 4K display.

To try to work around this, I got SwitchResX and set it to one of the 1080p60Hz options, which seems to match what the old computer was outputting. Unfortunately that only worked for the large TV displays - the old, small, monitor is still showing "bad resolution" messages, and while it does display an image, it is incredibly distorted (color issues).

Is there a way I can get my new MacMini to output over the HDMI the exact same way the old MacBook pro was outputting over the thunderbolt->HDMI adapter? Or, since the output IS working for the TV's, is it likely that replacing the monitor would fix the issue?

Comment: Not knowing exactly what HDMI switcher you are using, I recommend you look into  [Kramer VM-4H2](https://www.amazon.com/Kramer-VM-4H2-Electronics/dp/B01MSC0PD5) with 4K resolution, or a [Kramer VM-4HC](https://www.amazon.com/Kramer-High-Quality-Distributor-VM-4HC/dp/B00CQCYF3I). I use a 4H2 to split a 4K PTZ camera output to a 55" 4K display monitor, a livestream system, and a 1080p monitor for the livestream/camera operator. The prices are higher than switchers from other manufacturers, but I've found Kramer devices to be superlative. Only a satisfied customer - no financial ties to Kramer.

Comment: How is the color distorted? If it's just "colors too bright/dark/washed out" distorted and not "acid trip" distorted, you might just need to set the right HDMI range on your TV.

Comment: Total acid trip/psychedelic distortion, along with a message along the lines of "input not support". You can barely make out the actual picture through it. And the TV's are fine, it's just the monitor that isn't working. If there was a switcher that DIDN'T have 4K resolution, that might work too, since the problem appears to be that the computer is convinced it needs to output 4K, when in fact only 1080 is supported.